# Compiling boost 1.59 with gcc-4.8. how to eliminate warnings?

Tags: boost, warnings, gcc4.8

./boost/python/cast.hpp:73:20: warning: typedef 'must_be_a_complete_type' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
/usr/include/python2.7/object.h:115:51: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]

Comment: you should probably add some more information, like how you invoked the build process ...

Comment: I am doing a manual build with ./bootstrap.sh ./b2 install. I tried editing the boost makefile to supress the warning with cflags    = -w -O3 -Iinclude -isystem $(BOOST_ROOT) -Wno-unused-local-typedefs but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: These are warnings. This is pretty normal when building boost. Look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#boost-root-directory) in paragraph § 4.1.